# What's the difference between the following two ways to create an executable JAR?

Tags: java, jar

I was reading up on how-to create a [jar file in java](http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/how-to-make-jar-from-java-sourceclass-files/) , so the way is like this :

```
jar cmf mainclass.txt example.jar *.class
```

I was curious about why we use `*.class` rather than specifically saying something like example.class ? I have a directory with many class files, how would it know which one to use?  [Here is how my directory looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvNnW.png) thanks!

EDIT: Thanks a lot I created a new directory and this saved my about 50% bytes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is simply a wildcard for the shell and expands to match all the files that end with `.class` in the current directory.

If you don't want that ... instead you would list the specific `.class` files you want to add.

*Typically* you use `*.class` because often the `.class` files in a directory make up a project, and thus all of them are needed in the `.jar`.

Comment: Thank you so much! My jar was originally  8,397 bytes, however When I tried again in a new directory, the new file is 4,408 bytes  -   so it was adding in extra class files .Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

specifying *.class will include all the files with .class extension. You should use this only when you know that you need all the .class files in your jar

Answer (score 1):

The .jar file need only the .class needed

EDIT: In this case, the * include all .class files.

Comment: Only if it actually needs all the class, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: Obviously, only the .class needed

Comment: @scgr - The point Dave is making is that your statement is not necessarily true. What if I have a class in that directory that I don't need for the `.jar` I'm building?